# remote desktop unable to connect to windows 10 pro

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I upgraded my Windows 10 to Windows Pro to allow access via remote desktop but I am unable to access the now Windows 10 Pro system from a Windows 7 system. I get the error message...

> Remote Desktop can't find computer Dell2. This might mean that Dell2
>   does not belong to the specified network. Verify the computer name and
>   domain that you are trying to connect to.

I have verified that settings > remote desktop is enabled.

I have verified that Defender Firewall apps has Remote Desktop has both private and public checked.

I have turned off "allow connection only from computer running remote desktop with network level authentication."

I have added allowed User accounts to the Settings > Remote Desktop

The windows 7 system is able to do a remote desktop to a older XP system.

The Windows 10 system is able to connect to the old xp system.

All systems share the same ethernet.

Any hints as to what I might do to get this working appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have basic network connectivity?  Can the machines ping each other?

Comment: Have you enabled network discovery on Win 10? Use the IP address instead if you’re having trouble. Also disable the firewall.

Comment: @appleoddity - Network discovery was disabled on the target system, the windows 10 pro system.  After enabling it I was able to remote desktop from the windows 7 system to the windows 10 pro system.  Thank you very much for this hint.  If you were to add it as an answer, I'd be very happy to accept it!  This means a great deal to me as I'm about to have a hip replacement and I need to be able to do the remote desktop to avoid using ten steps to our lower level.